# Keyboard and Trackpad do not work when Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 12 is stacked

Tags: thinkpad

I work in an IT department and each year we roll out a bunch of laptops. This year we used the Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 12. Because I work with so many of them, I'm inevitably going to stack them on top of each other to save space. I noticed something interesting today; the trackpad and keyboard on one of these laptops stops working when the laptop is sitting on top of another laptop.

Once the laptop is moved so it isn't on top of another one, the problem goes away. As far as I can tell with my brief testing with a paperclip, there aren't any magnetic regions anywhere on the laptops. In fact, because they all use SSDs, there shouldn't be anything that would be affected by a magnet in them anyway.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue? It's not a hindrance to my work, but it has stumped me for a couple of hours now.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SuperUser! Congrats on the awesome question... We don't get many like these around here! ;D

Comment: Thanks! I've lurked around here and StackExchange in general for a while, but I though this was worthy of a post.

Comment: Did you test this when the lower laptop (one your stacking one on top of) is completely turned off? Ideally with the windows fastboot option disabled

Comment: Perhaps try measuring with a compass, because some magnetic field does seem like the likely cause. I found some other posts with laptop stacking issues. There the conclusion was that it must be a magnetic field. http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19566374

Answer (score 2):

The Yoga's have a magnet in the end of them that tells the laptop when the screen is closed. It prevents the keyboard from being pressed by the lid.

When you stack the laptops on top of each other, the magnet in the screen of the bottom Yoga is activating the magnet in the keyboard part of the other.